# Hibernate:IllegalArgumentException : in class: ... getter method of property: id

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public class Media implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private MediaKind mediaKind;
    private String name;
    private byte[] cover;
    private Date releaseDate;
    private Integer contentRating;
    private String summary;
    private Set mediaCrews = new HashSet(0);
    private Set mediaInstances = new HashSet(0);
    private Set ratings = new HashSet(0);
    private Set genres = new HashSet(0);
    static SessionFactory mediaFactory=Main.config.buildSessionFactory();

    public Media() {
    }

    public Media(int id, MediaKind mediaKind, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mediaKind = mediaKind;
        this.name = name;
        Session mediaSession = mediaFactory.getCurrentSession();

    }

    public Media(int id, MediaKind mediaKind, String name, byte[] cover,
            Date releaseDate, Integer contentRating, String summary,
            Set mediaCrews, Set mediaInstances, Set ratings, Set genres) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mediaKind = mediaKind;
        this.name = name;
        this.cover = cover;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.contentRating = contentRating;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.mediaCrews = mediaCrews;
        this.mediaInstances = mediaInstances;
        this.ratings = ratings;
        this.genres = genres;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MediaKind getMediaKind() {
        return this.mediaKind;
    }

    public void setMediaKind(MediaKind mediaKind) {
        this.mediaKind = mediaKind;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public byte[] getCover() {
        return this.cover;
    }

    public void setCover(byte[] cover) {
        this.cover = cover;
    }

    public Date getReleaseDate() {
        return this.releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(Date releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public Integer getContentRating() {
        return this.contentRating;
    }

    public void setContentRating(Integer contentRating) {
        this.contentRating = contentRating;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return this.summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public Set getMediaCrews() {
        return this.mediaCrews;
    }

    public void setMediaCrews(Set mediaCrews) {
        this.mediaCrews = mediaCrews;
    }

    public Set getMediaInstances() {
        return this.mediaInstances;
    }

    public void setMediaInstances(Set mediaInstances) {
        this.mediaInstances = mediaInstances;
    }

    public Set getRatings() {
        return this.ratings;
    }

    public void setRatings(Set ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    public Set getGenres() {
        return this.genres;
    }

    public void setGenres(Set genres) {
        this.genres = genres;
    }
    public static java.util.List<Media> search(String name){
        java.util.List list;
        Session sess=mediaFactory.getCurrentSession();
        sess.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria=sess.createCriteria(Media.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", "%"+name+"%"));
        list= criteria.list();
        Hibernate.initialize(list);
        sess.getTransaction().commit();
        //connection=sess.close();

        return list;

    }
    public ArrayList<MediaInstance> availableInstances(){
        //sess.beginTransaction();
        Session sess=mediaFactory.openSession();
        sess.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria=sess.createCriteria(MediaInstance.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("media", name));
        sess.getTransaction().commit();
        return (ArrayList<MediaInstance>)criteria.list();
        /*MediaInstance[] instances=(MediaInstance[]) mediaInstances.toArray();

        ArrayList<MediaInstance> mediaInstanceList=new ArrayList<MediaInstance>(Arrays.asList(instances));
        for(int i=0;i<mediaInstanceList.size();i++){
            MediaInstance instance=mediaInstanceList.get(i);
            if(!instance.isAvailable()|!instance.isSellable()){
                mediaInstanceList.remove(instance);
            }
        }
        //sess.getTransaction().commit();
        //sess.close();
        return mediaInstanceList;*/
    }

}
```

here is my second class mediaInstance:

```
public class MediaInstance implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private MediaType mediaType;
    private Media media;
    private String price;
    private boolean available;
    private boolean sellable;
    private Set rents = new HashSet(0);
    private Set purchases = new HashSet(0);

    public MediaInstance() {
    }

    public MediaInstance(int id, MediaType mediaType, Media media,
            String price, boolean available, boolean sellable) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
        this.media = media;
        this.price = price;
        this.available = available;
        this.sellable = sellable;
    }

    public MediaInstance(int id, MediaType mediaType, Media media,
            String price, boolean available, boolean sellable, Set rents,
            Set purchases) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
        this.media = media;
        this.price = price;
        this.available = available;
        this.sellable = sellable;
        this.rents = rents;
        this.purchases = purchases;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MediaType getMediaType() {
        return this.mediaType;
    }

    public void setMediaType(MediaType mediaType) {
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
    }

    public Media getMedia() {
        return this.media;
    }

    public void setMedia(Media media) {
        this.media = media;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return this.available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        this.available = available;
    }

    public boolean isSellable() {
        return this.sellable;
    }

    public void setSellable(boolean sellable) {
        this.sellable = sellable;
    }

    public Set getRents() {
        return this.rents;
    }

    public void setRents(Set rents) {
        this.rents = rents;
    }

    public Set getPurchases() {
        return this.purchases;
    }

    public void setPurchases(Set purchases) {
        this.purchases = purchases;
    }

}
```

When I try to call `criteria.list()` in method `availableInstances()` I get this exception.

```
May 27, 2014 1:22:56 PM org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter get
ERROR: HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: Media, getter method of property: id
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of Media.id
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1994)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1965)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    at MediaInstance.availableInstances(MediaInstance.java:125)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
    ... 23 more
```

I used JBoss tools to generate the classes and mapping files from my database.
so I don't think that the problem is in mapping files.

Comment: Can you post stacktrace please.

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria query doesn't seem right. You are trying to filter by an instance of media entity but passing the name as parameter.

Try something like this:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("media", this));
```

Comment: what you got this time?

Comment: May 27, 2014 4:25:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
May 27, 2014 4:25:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 250

Comment: May 27, 2014 4:25:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
May 27, 2014 4:25:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 250

Comment: Oh yes, `like` does not work with object instances. Use `eq` instead. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument passed to the static "like" method (or "eq" method, and so on) of the Restrictions static class must be of the same type of the field identified by the first string (first argument).
In your example:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("media", name));
```

"name" is a String while "media" field of the MediaInstance class is a instance of Media. You should substitute "name" with a media instance, even the Media instance itself executing the "availableInstances" method, so:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("media", this));
```